# Dynamic Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

Hello I am having an issue with Python Threads.

What I am aiming to do is create a function that launches other functions as a thread when called. Unfortunately I am running into two issues (Besides my lack of knowledge in Python.)

1: If I put quotes around: `"globals()[T_Name[i]]()"` it treats it as a string and executes the code normally.
2: If I omit the quotes around `globals()[T_Name[i]]()` it launches the first function immediately and does not process through the rest of the script to launch it as a thread.

If anyone could provide some insight I apologize for the formatting I will be bumping it up to PEP 8 standards eventually.

Code:

```
import threading
import time

T_Name=("Write_Done", "Write_Pin")
T_Time=[]
Tr=[]
for i, Nu in enumerate(T_Name):
    Tr.append("T" + str(i))
    T_Time.append("0")

def Write_Done():
    while True:
       print("Done")
       time.sleep(5)

def Write_Pin():
    while True:
       print("Pin")
       time.sleep(15)

def Thread_Checker():
    while True:
       time.sleep(5)
       for i, TH in enumerate(T_Time):
           if (time.time() - int(TH)) < 30:
              pass
              #thread is still rocking
           else:
              #thread has failed Time to get her done.
              Tr[i] = threading.Thread(target=("globals()[T_Name[i]]()"))
              print("starting" + T_Name[i])
              Tr[i].daemon = True
              Tr[i].start()
       print("Test if alive")
       if Tr[0].is_alive():
          print("I LIVE!")
       else:
          print("I ded")

Thread_Checker()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda function to create something that is actually callable as the target, but defers the call of what you want until the target is called.

```
Tr[i] = threading.Thread(target=lambda: globals()[T_Name[i]]())
```

Comment: Implementing the Lambda forces the

Comment: Implementing the Lambda gives me an invalid key error now. As where previously I was unable to call the function.

Comment: But that is at least happening in a new thread right? Verify it is now in a thread, and if so you are now on to the next problem with your code whatever that may be. You have an answer for how to have it be in the thread at least.

Comment: Disregard that. Graham is correct. The issue is the `globals()[T_Name[i]]()' and `locals()[T_Name[i]]()` are refrencing the namespace in the function and when the function is called inside a main thread the functions are not listed as they are not referenced.